# logic for sync in Dexie JS

Tags: dexie

[In the docs](https://dexie.org/cloud/docs/access-control#introduction), we see

> each user maintains a copy of the part of the database that is accessible for that user

Is it possible to create more granular logic for how the DB is synced? For example, lets say I can view the data of 10 other users, but I only want the most recent 20 records of each other user to be synchronized to my local DB.